# django-session-timeout: The current path, accounts/login/, didn't match any of these

Tags: django, session-timeout

I try to implement an autologout after user inactivity (lets says 15 minutes)
I have read many things and there is as my understanding at least two possibilities:

1. use the django-session-timeout
2. write a personnalized middleware

I try first to use the django-session-timeout but got the error:

> The current path, accounts/login/, didn't match any of these.

in my settings.py I have defined

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
```

here is my project urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('registration/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('monitor/', include('monitor.urls')),
    path('randomization/', include('randomization.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**EDIT:**
I had LOGIN_URL: 'home' and now it works with my superuser admin but not with other users because I could not navigate anymore

Answer (score 0):

Setting `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL` doesn't matter in this case because django-session-timeout isn't referencing it. Upon the session expiring django-session-timeout is [calling `redirect_to_login`](https://github.com/labd/django-session-timeout/blob/0.0.4/src/django_session_timeout/middleware.py#L30). If we look at Django's [code for `redirect_to_login`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2.7/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L172) it also has nothing to do with `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL`.

If this isn't the behaviour that you want you might need to write your own middleware, since it doesn't seem that django-session-timeout offers the ability to modify this behaviour.

Comment: thanks for replying. In fact, I had to add LOGIN_URL = 'home' and it works.